# How can I extract a full path from the PATH environment variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, cmd

I want to extract a full path from the `PATH` environment variable with native cmd tools. Consider the following `PATH` content:

> C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\WI
>   NDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQ
>   L Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Fi
>   les\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\10
>   0\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\program fil
>   es\nmap\;C:\Program Files\WinRAR\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Progra
>   m Files\hydra-5.4-win\;C:\Program Files\john1701\run;C:\dig;;C:\cygwin;C:\wamp\b
>   in\mysql\mysql5.0.45\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Tail4win;C:\Program Files\Overlook Fing 1.1\bin

I want to extract only the following path:

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin;

Is `FOR` capable of such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `for` to tokenize at `;` but you need to take care of paths that have a `;` in them (and thus need quotes). All in all I'd say you'd build a pretty brittle solution with pretty much code at this point.

If you want to know where a certain executable is, then

```
for %%i in ("mysql.exe") do @echo.%%~$PATH:i
```

will tell you that (or not, if it's nowhere in the `PATH`).

**UPDATE:** Ok, I got it. One nasty little batch file follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set p=%PATH%
:loop
for %%i in ("notepad.exe") do call :setvar "%%~$p:i"
if not :%x%:==:: (call :clearpath & goto loop)
goto :eof

:setvar
    set x=%~1
goto :eof

:clearpath
    echo %x%
    for %%x in ("!x!") do set d=%%~dpx
    set d=!d:~,-1!
    set p=!p:%d%=!
goto :eof
```

This will print all matching paths from `PATH` where `notepad.exe` was found (the first program I know off the top of my head to be in two places here). Adapt accordingly for your problem.

`:clearpath` simply deletes the found path from the variable and then we try matching again, until no match is left.

That said, this is still very un-pretty.

Comment: Thank you 
Your hint is very helpful

Comment: %~$PATH:I searches the directories listed in the PATH environmentvariable and expands %I to the fully qualified name of the first one found.If the environmentvariable name is not defined or the file is not found by the search, then this modifier expands to the empty string if so is anyway to getrest

Comment: I know what the docs say on that. What exactly is your question?

Comment: there are serveral mysql instllation in the path as you can see in the question %~$PATH:I return  only the  first one how can i get the rest of mysql  instllation  from same path

Comment: anyways your tip was very helpful thanks alot for your help don't bother i'll try myself

Comment: Added a solution. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the path, why do you need to find it in the PATH string?

Or to put it another way, do you know a way of recognising that string, given that it may vary between installations?

Comment: i want to make it portable as much as possible because i'm going to apply it on several servers and i think each installation has mysql bath inside %PATH%

Comment: Yes, but when the user installs MySQL, are they allowed to choose any install path? If so, how will you know which part of the PATH variable is the MySQL install path?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but i'll assume that mysql are in %PATH%

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, you can use vbscript.

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strSearch = objArgs(0)
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshPath = WshShell.Environment("SYSTEM")
strPath =WshPath("Path")

s = Split(strPath,";")
For i=LBound(s) To UBound(s)
    If InStr(1,s(i),strSearch,1) > 0 Then
        WScript.Echo s(i)
    End If 
Next
```

save the above as findpath.vbs and use it like this on the command line to find any string you want within the PATH variable:

c:\test> cscript //nologo findpath.vbs mysql

In a batch file, to get the results, use a for loop