# get current users path variable without system path using cmd

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, registry

When I'm logged in with my standard user (which is also an admin) the command `echo %PATH%` returns system's path + user's path. How can I get the user's path only?

E.g. when my current user's path is `C:\ruby;C:\java\bin` and system's path is `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%` the command above returns `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;C:\ruby;C:\java\bin` but I only want to have `C:\ruby;C:\java\bin` in order to be able to append to user's path permanently without system's path trash included.

My goal is to append a directory to the path variable. I tried to do this with the command `setx PATH %PATH%;C:\ruby\bin` which ruined my path variable because of the system's path.

Comment: I dont know if you can do that on Windows, but you can run `set` in **cmd** to see all the **environment variables** you have defined, maybe you could find another variable that work for you.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but sadly that didn't help

Comment: Maybe you could explain what is the purpose of recieving those values, and someone could find a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the variable exists, *because it doesn't by default*, you could get that using the registry.

Here's one method from the Command prompt:

```dos
For /F "Skip=2Tokens=1-2*" %A In ('Reg Query HKCU\Environment /V PATH 2^>Nul') Do @Echo %A=%C
```

Comment: How might this be adapted to include in a batch script?

Comment: Very easily @DavidFoster, the OP did not use the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, only the [[tag:cmd]] one, so I provided my answer accordingly. To use it in a batch file, change it to this:`@For /F "Skip=2Tokens=1-2*" %%A In ('Reg Query HKCU\Environment /V PATH 2^>Nul') Do @Echo %%A=%%C`. If my comment/solution helps you, please consider upvoting the above answer; thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Compo. I found more info on the reasoning behind one (`%`) or two (`%%`) percentage signs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509652/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-a-cmd-file).

Answer (score 7):

Another way using PowerShell.

```
(Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\Environment).PATH
```

Or, from a cmd.exe shell.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "(Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\Environment).PATH"
```

In order to retrieve the variable without interpolation.

```
(Get-Item -Path HKCU:\Environment).GetValue('PATH', $null, 'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')

powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-Item -Path HKCU:\Environment).GetValue('PATH', $null, 'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')"
```

Comment: So it can't be done natively in cmd?
I'm trying to add a folder to the user PATH, using `setx PATH "C:\;%PATH%`, but it's mixing them up; adds the system path to the user path :/

Comment: @GandalfSaxe - Yes, `powershell.exe` is a native executable just as much as `reg.exe`. Use `reg /?` to find out about it if you do not want to move in the direction that Microsoft says is the future or if you must support older, unsupported versions of Windows.