# Structured Data Linter ruby installation problem

Tags: ruby, rake, structured-data, linter

I have a relatively big corpus of structured data, which I need to validate. I am planning to use Ruby Structured Data Linter from this repo https://github.com/structured-data/linter to automate the validation. After cloning the repo and installation of all required packages when I try to run

`rake schema:examples`

I get an error

```
C:\Users\anast\Projects\Schema\linter>rake schema:examples
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rdf/linter
C:/Users/anast/Projects/Schema/linter/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How can I fix this? It's worth to mention that I already tried to add the lib folder to PATH.

```
C:\Users\anast\Projects\Schema\linter>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.1 (2020-03-31 patchlevel 83) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/anast/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby27/bin/ruby.exe
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd/git.EXE
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby27/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/anast/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - C:/Users/anast/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - C:\Windows\system32
     - C:\Windows
     - C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
     - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
     - C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
     - "C:\MinGW\bin
     - C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin"
     - C:\Users\anast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38
     - C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\swigwin-4.0.2
     - C:\Program Files\nodejs\
     - C:\Users\anast\Projects\Schema\linter\lib
     - C:\Ruby27\bin
     - C:\Ruby26\bin
     - C:\Users\anast\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
     -
     - C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.4\bin
     -
     - C:\Users\anast\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
     - C:\Users\anast\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I have absolutely no experience with ruby so would be grateful for any help :)

Comment: did you run `rake schema:examples` ?  Also can you add to your question what is the output of `gem env` ?

Comment: yes I tried to run this command, I added more detailed output and `gem env` to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ruby binary paths in your $PATH variable, but it looks like you need to remove `C:\Ruby26\bin`

Any ruby script or program which contains a `Gemfile` you need to install the dependencies by the following steps:

`cd` into the root of the project and run these commands

```
gem install rubygems
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Then try to run your rake commands again. But also the documentation for this project says to run

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundler
```

The instructions on the setup and how to actually run this project are not exactly clear but make sure to check the [setup notes section](https://github.com/structured-data/linter#setup-notes) which appear to conflict somewhat with instructions for [running locally](https://github.com/structured-data/linter#running-locally)

I would try both methods after getting your `PATH` fixed and dependencies installed properly. I'm not on Windows but if you may need to refer to answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289762/remove-unwanted-path-name-from-path-variable-via-batch) for help with that.